# Triangle Equality in a normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The following statement is true or false:

If $x, y$ are elements of a normed linear space, then $$\|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\| \iff x = 0\ \text{or}\ y = tx$$
for some $t ≥ 0$.

What I have tried is as follows:

It is clear that if $x = 0\ \text{or}\ y = tx $ then the equality will hold. But for the converse part, let
\begin{align*}
\|x+y\|& =\|x\|+\|y\|\\
\implies \|x+y\|^2 & =(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2\\
\end{align*} 
After that I stuck. Also in the following article [Characterization of the norm triangle equality](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jmi-03-35.pdf), I have read that in the case of a strictly convex normed linear space $V$, the
equality $\|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$ holds for nonzero vectors $x,y ∈ V$ if and only if $\frac{x}{\|x\|} = \frac{y}{\|y\|} $.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: How do you come to the inner product in a normed linear space? What if there is no inner product?

Comment: Yeah, this will create a problem. I'll delete this. But then how will I proceed.

Comment: See, the point is that if your space is infinite dimensional, then there exist norms for which the above does not hold! You can have all kinds of norms in such a space. So the above is wrong. In finite dimensions, it holds because any two norms are equivalent in finite dimensions.

Comment: Do you have any counter example for the infinite dimensional space.

Comment: Oh, I've made a disastrous mistake. this actually trivially doesn't even hold for finite dimensions! The below example by @copperhat shows why. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The above holds only when you consider the **standard norm** on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\|(x,y)\| = |x|+|y|$. Then $\|(1,0)\| + \|(0,1)\| = \|(1,1)\|$.

Comment: This is not true for the $L^\infty$ norm on $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The example of the $\ell^1$-norm on $\mathbb R^2$ illustrating the failure of the proposition in general by user @copper.hat is very nice. In this answer I'll give a substitute that is true in inner product spaces.

Let $(X,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a real or complex inner product space. (We use $\Re z$ to denote the real part of $z\in\mathbb C$.)

**Proposition.** *Suppose $e_1,\dots,e_n$ in $X$ are unit vectors and $|e_1 + \dots + e_n| = n$. Then $e_1=e_2=\dots=e_n$.*

*Proof.* We use induction on $n$. The case $n = 2$ is the most important, the case $n = 1$ being trivial. In case $n = 2$, consider that
$$
4 = \langle e_1+e_2,e_1+e_2\rangle = 2 + 2\Re\langle e_1,e_2\rangle.
$$
Therefore, $\langle e_1-e_2,e_1-e_2\rangle$ is equal to
$$
2 - 2\Re\langle e_1,e_2\rangle = 0.
$$
Suppose the claim is true for some $n\ge 2$, and consider the case $n+1$. By assumption and the triangle inequality,
$$
n+1=|e_1+\dots+e_{n+1}|\le |e_1+\dots+e_n|+1\le n+1,
$$
so all inequalities are equalities, and in particular,
$$
|e_1+\dots+e_n| = n.
$$
By induction, all $e_1=e_2=\dots=e_n$. Similarly, $e_2=\dots=e_{n+1}$, hence all $e_1=e_2=\dots=e_{n+1}$. $\square$

Note this is not a case of the ["all horses are the same color"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color) fallacy of induction because we verified the case $n=2$ as the base of our induction.